# Azure AD B2C User Attributes

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a requirement to take new User attributes for users already authenticated in Azure AD B2C. Is there any way i can force the user to provide the new attributes before logging in next time.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more on this? Are you allowing users to register without requiring a complete set of attributes? How is what you are asking for different than perhaps the profile edit page?

Comment: Initially we did ask only for State of the user, but as we expanded a requirement for user city has risen and wee need that additional information.  We are able to do not it checking the attribute in code and redirecting the user to profile edit but just wanted to know if there is some better way to achieve this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using custom policy, at the time of user sign-in, check if the desired user attribute value is not null. If it is, then you can ask them to provide the values for missing user attributes. You can also build more sophisticated logic but this should get you started.